# django admin view and edit only what the user has create

Tags: python, django, permissions, admin

I have different models like this for example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

All my model have a foreign key on user.
Is there a way in the django admin to see only post the user have create and edit them? Or should I do my own custom admin?

Comment: This is specifically demonstrated in the docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Comment: I'm trying to understand the given example in the doc. I copy and past it it didn't do what i want. I want to log in the admin with an user and be able to see and edit only my own post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman, there is an example in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).
Here what do I have to add to my Postadmin model.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PostAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```